# SQL populating table with calculation from other tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

grades_table = has 100 rows of students with grades i.e.

```
        Student        Mark
          Joe           64
          Mark          50
```

percentage_table = a table which has a percentage to a grade i.e.

```
         Grade         Mark
           A            70+
           B            60+
           C            50+
```

Is it possible in SQL to populate a new table called Overall, with the grade calculation?  For example,

```
       Student         Grade
        Joe             B
        Mark            C
```

I've looked at IN and BETWEEN.  But I can't quite understand how to calculate the ranges.  I'm new to SQL and any help or point to the right direction would be great.

Comment: Split percentage_table's mark column into two columns, markmin and markmax.

Comment: You generally shouldn't create a *table* for this calculation - you'd normally want either a result set (for a single ad-hoc query) or a *view*. The point being, don't *store* data that can be calculated. As soon as you store calculated data, you introduce the opportunity for the calculated data to be out of sync with the base data.

Comment: even if it's possible to use a single column, I would still suggest you to use two columns, it's cleaner and doesn't look like a "hack"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split percentage table's mark column into two columns, `markmin` and `markmax`. Then `JOIN` the tables as:

```
select g.student, p.grade
from grades g
  join percentage p ON g.mark between p.markmin and p.markmax
```

Or, according to later suggested *If I changed the scenario slightly, and only had one mark column in the percentage_table, so only 60+, 70+*:

Here I assume `(A, 70)` means 70 and above is grade `A`. Do a `GROUP BY` with `MIN` to find "lowest" grade alphabetically:

```
select g.student, min(p.grade)
from grades g
  join percentage p ON g.mark <= p.mark
group by g.student
```

Alternatively, use a correlated sub-select:

```
select g.student, (select min(p.grade) from percentage p
                   where g.mark <= p.mark)
from grades g
```

Comment: Cool!  If I changed the scenario slightly, and only had one mark column in the percentage_table, so only 60+, 70+ etc, how could I modify this answer?

Comment: quick question. g.grade.. how does this work when there isnt a grade attribute in the grades table?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have two different columns in your table `percentage_table`:

```
Grade | MarkMin | MarkMax
A     | 70      | Null
B     | 60      | 69
C     | 50      | 59
```

Then you can just use a JOIN:

```
SELECT g.student, p.Mark
FROM
  grades_table AS g LEFT JOIN percentage_table AS p
  ON (g.Mark >= p.MarkMin OR p.MarkMin IS NULL)
     AND (g.Mark<=p.MarkMax OR p.MarkMax IS NULL)
```

70+ which means >= 70 can then be inserted as (70, Null).
If you want to have a <=49 then you can add a mark as (Null, 49).